# Rails Command Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner in Ruby. I am trying to start the Rails Server. Then I got the following error. I uninstalled and installed again but this did not remove the error. I use Rails version 5.1 and Ruby with Version 2.3.3 in Windows 10. 
How do I fix this?

```
 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load': C:/Sites/myrubyblog/config/routes.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:119:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from C:/Sites/myrubyblog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Sites/myrubyblog/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    from C:/Sites/myrubyblog/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from C:/Sites/myrubyblog/config.ru:in `new'
    from C:/Sites/myrubyblog/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:148:in `log_to_stdout'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:102:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

And when I opened routes.rb the Syntax looked like this.

```
#Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'home/index'
root :to=>'home#index' 
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
end
```

Comment: Obviously you have a syntax error in your `routes.rb` file. Show its content.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You commented out the first line, that is what causes the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is `routes.rb`

Change your `routes.rb` as following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'
  root :to =>'home#index' 
end
```